# Add filter based on specified releaseDate in Sparql query on DBpedia Endpoint

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

Goodmorning everyone.
I have a SPARQL query which, given the artist's name (as in this example 'Drake'), returns his songs with various information attached such as album, genre, release date and label.
I would like to parameterize the query as well as for the artist name also by date (so get a filter by date)
For example, if I wanted to get the songs that were released after 2010-01-01 what should I do?
Thanks in advance to anyone who has a solution.
Here is the query:

```
select distinct
?song
(replace(?song_label ,"en","","") as ?song_label )
(replace(?album_name_l ,"en","","") as ?album_name_l )
(replace(?artist_l ,"en","","") as ?artist_l )
(max(?releaseDate) as ?releaseDate)
(GROUP_CONCAT( distinct ?genre_l;SEPARATOR=",") AS ?genre_l)
(GROUP_CONCAT(?recordLabel_l;SEPARATOR=",") AS ?recordLabel_l)
where
{
?song a dbo:Single .
?song rdfs:label ?song_label.

?song dbo:album ?album_name.
?album_name rdfs:label ?album_name_l.

?song dbo:artist ?artist.
?artist rdfs:label ?artist_l.

?song dbo:genre ?genre.
?genre rdfs:label ?genre_l.

?song dbo:recordLabel ?recordLabel.
?recordLabel rdfs:label ?recordLabel_l.

?song dbo:releaseDate ?releaseDate.
FILTER(langMatches(lang(?song_label),"en")).
FILTER(langMatches(lang(?album_name_l),"en")).
FILTER(langMatches(lang(?artist_l),"en")).
FILTER(langMatches(lang(?genre_l),"en")).
FILTER(langMatches(lang(?recordLabel_l),"en")).
BIND( 'Drake' AS ?name)
FILTER (strstarts(lcase(str(?artist_l)), lcase(str(?name))))
}
group by ?song ?song_label ?album_name_l ?artist_l ?releaseDate
```

Comment: just get the release date of the song and use a filter or not? Where exactly is the problem here? What doesn't work with the filter?

Comment: `FILTER(?releaseDate > "2010-01-01"^^xsd:date)`

Comment: by the way, scanning the labels for name is worst case and slow, you should use the Virtuoso fulltext search and you should also filter the entities by some type(s), e.g. Musician or something